# pass values in array without a return in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory

So I need to pass three numbers and an array to a void function that sorts the numbers and puts it into the array. I then to be able to access the array from main to print out the numbers.

How do I have my function put the numbers in the array and allow main access to it without returning anything?

Thank you

EDIT: Here's my function as of now

```
void f_sort(int x, int y, int z, int *list)
{
    const int arraySize = 3;            //Constant for the size of array
    int element = 0;                    //Holds numerical value for array element
    int num1 = x;                       //Holds value of first entered number
    int num2 = y;                       //Holds value of second entered number
    int num3 = z;                       //Holds value of third entered number
    int temp;                           //Holds value of number being swapped

                                        //If the first number is larger then the second
    if (num1 > num2)
    {
        //Swap their values
        temp = num2;
        num2 = num1;
        num1 = temp;
    }

    //If the first number is larger then the third
    if (num1 > num3)
    {
        //Swap their values
        temp = num3;
        num3 = num1;
        num1 = temp;
    }

    //If the second number is larger then the third
    if (num2 > num3)
    {
        //Swap their values
        temp = num3;
        num3 = num2;
        num2 = temp;
    }

    //Add the values into the array in ascending order
    list[0] = num1;
    list[1] = num2;
    list[2] = num3;

    return;
}

int main()
{
    //Declaring an array
    int *list[3];
    //Declaring variables
    int n = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;

printf("\n\nThe program will now take three numbers and sort them in assending order. Enter the first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Enter the second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("Enter the third number: ");
    scanf("%d", &z);

    f_sort(x, y, z, *list);

    printf("The numbers in order are: %d %d %d", *list[0], *list[1], *list[2]);
}
```

Comment: Just assign values to the array(which is actually a pointer to X inside the  function) in the function?

Comment: I don't see your actual problem. Or you don't see you already solved it. Maybe you should rethink your question.

Comment: When I try to print it out in main, I'm not getting the right values printed

Comment: Good you posted `main` then, as the problem seems to be there... Post a [mcve]! How do you know the values are correct inside the function? (Note that the functions is too complicated for its task and you should use a `swap` function.)

Comment: I'll update in a second with my main. The compiler throws an error when it tries to put a value in list from the function

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return the array to print its elements. Simply pass the array like this:

```
void f_sort(int x, int y, int z, int list[]) {
    ...
}

int main() {
    int x, y, z, list[10];
    f_sort(x, y, z, list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: That will pass a pointer the the first element. You cannot pass an array directly in C. This is exactly what OP already does.

Comment: I can't change the parameters

Comment: Wait, does `int *list` mean the function will accept a variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
int *list[3];
```

Creates an array of pointers, not the array of `int`s you want.

```
int list[3];
```

Is what you want. So you can eliminate all pointer notation in `main`.

```
f_sort(x, y, z, list);
printf("The numbers in order are: %d %d %d", list[0], list[1], list[2]);
```